# Spring Cloud Task status shown as complete even when the batch job fails

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

I have a task with 2 batch jobs, both jobs run but one of them fails. The status of the particular task is still shown as complete.
i read about setting the *spring.cloud.task.batch.failOnJobFailure* property. When i set this property to true while running the task it gives me the following error:

````
o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

java.lang.AbstractMethodError: null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isSingleton(AbstractBeanFactory.java:402) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:447) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:415) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.getLifecycleBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:273) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:131) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:112) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:852) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.2
```.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at com.mediaiq.appnexus.batch.AppnexusBatchServiceApplication.main(AppnexusBatchServiceApplication.java:53) [classes!/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [aiq-appnexus-batch-service-3.23.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [aiq-appnexus-batch-service-3.23.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [aiq-appnexus-batch-service-3.23.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [aiq-appnexus-batch-service-3.23.1.jar:na]
````

Comment: Looks like you are using incompatible library versions.

Comment: Any idea which ones?

Comment: which version of spring cloud task are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a version incompatibility issue.

There's a duplicate thread via [spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-ui#917#issuecomment-425945144](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-ui/issues/917#issuecomment-425945144) that summarizes the various version compatibility scenarios.

If there are continued problems on the compatible stack, it'd be good to review a reproducible sample App.